# To RAID or not?

Tags: raid, sync, rsync

**I have the following setup:**

- HP Microserver N40L
- 1 x 250GB HDisk
- 1 x 1TB HDisk
- 2 x 2TB Hdisks
- Ubuntu for OS

**Currently I use the server to backup the following hardware:**

- 1 x MacBook Pro running Windows and OSX
- 2 x iPhones (doing backups of the photo's)

I'm running my server headless and keyboardless but have WebMin installed.

I want to safely store photo's and home video's and make the odd backup of my laptop. Initially I planned on setting up my two 2TB disks with RAID 1 but it feels like a waste of space for me (My 1TB disk is almost full and it has images + backups of 2 laptops + photo's and videos. After clearing out junk I will probably end up with about 600GB of data I want backed up).

And here is the question - would it not be better for me to set up rsync between the disks or something that can keep them in sync? Then I don't need to worry about RAID issues, slow write speed due to double write etc etc...

I'm thinking that I would then have more space to also set up my server as a media server.

Any help & words of wisdom will be appreciated.

**Additional information:**
I try to keep up to date with the latest release of Ubuntu. Currently I'm on 14.10 but I see 15.04 is available.

I haven't prepped the 2TB disks yet which is why they reflect NTFS in the `parted --list` output below.

```
Model: ATA VB0250EAVER (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 250GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  248GB  248GB   primary   ext4            boot
 2      248GB   250GB  2011MB  extended
 5      248GB   250GB  2011MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA ST31000528AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  1000GB  1000GB  primary  ext4


Model: ATA ST2000DL001-9VT1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs


Model: ATA ST2000DL001-9VT1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ntfs
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output to `sudo parted --list` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And here is the question - would it not be better for me to set up rsync between the disks or something that can keep them in sync? Then I don't need to worry about RAID issues, slow write speed due to double write etc etc...

Setting up a full scheduled rsync between two "individual" disks is just making a worse, manual [RAID1](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Standard_RAID_levels#/RAID_1). If 1 TB is enough for you and you have 2x1TB of disks, just set up a RAID1. That way you also get increased read performance. And remember; one backup is no backup.

You may also want to look into solutions more tailored to Network Storage needs, such as [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/). FreeNAS specifically has a pretty slick and easy web interface AFAIK.

> I try to keep up to date with the latest release of Ubuntu. Currently I'm on 14.10 but I see 15.04 is avaialable.

While this is good, for servers I would recommend jumping between [LTS releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).

Comment: I can only agree with all of the above!  **;-)** **Cobus:** As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: I kinda like having a *nix server - I can add lotsa stuff on top of it as I please: media player, LAMP, proxy server (if necessary), also software RAID. I know about FreeNAS but have always figured (maybe out of ignorance) that it's going to 'limit' me because it only does storage. If for instance I want to store my movies on there I will have to get a hardware player (Apple TV or Android) to connect to the server and read the movies from there whereas if I use Ubuntu with XBMC then I can hook it up directly to the TV.

Comment: Hmm - I see FreeNAS requires about 8GB of RAM - I'm 6 short but that can be solved. I also see media software can be installed. Sounds like a vable option after all :) Is it absolutely necessary to have 8GB RAM?

Comment: @CobusvanRooyen http://olddoc.freenas.org/index.php/Hardware_Recommendations "It is possible to use ZFS on systems with less than 8 GB of RAM. However, FreeNAS® as distributed is configured to be suitable for systems meeting the sizing recommendations above. If you wish to use ZFS on a smaller memory system, some tuning will be necessary, and performance will be (likely substantially) reduced. ZFS will automatically disable pre-fetching (caching) on systems where it is not able to use at least 4 GB of memory just for ZFS cache and data structures."